# Check function return with jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

Hello I am starting to study unit tests with jest and I have a class that has a function with a return I wanted to test the return of that function, but I don't know what the correct way to do this

class:

```
interface HelloWord {
    hello: string
}

export class HelloWordController extends Controller{
    async handle (request: HelloWord): Promise<HttpResponse> {
        return ok({message: 'hello word'})
    }
}
```

OK: return:

```
export const ok = (data: any): HttpResponse => ({
  statusCode: 200,
  body: data
})
```

test:

```
describe("Hello word Controller ", () => {
  it("should receive a string with name: hello, and value: hello word", () => {
        const logger = new adptLogger({})
        const hellowordController = new HelloWordController(logger)
        expect(hellowordController.handle({hello: 'hello word'})).toEqual(ok)
    });
});
```

i got failed:

```
Expected: [Function ok]
Received: {}

   7 |              const logger = new adptLogger({})
   8 |              const hellowordController = new HelloWordController(logger)
>  9 |              expect(hellowordController.handle({hello: 'hello word'})).toEqual(ok)
     |                                                                        ^
  10 |      });
  11 | });
```

**edited:**

```
describe("Hello word Controller ", () => {
  let controller = {} as HelloWordController;
  let logger: adptLogger = {} as adptLogger;
  beforeEach(() => {
    logger = new adptLogger({});
    controller = new HelloWordController(logger);
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  it("should receive a string with name: hello, and value: hello word", async () => {
    const expedtedReturn = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: { message: "hello word" },
    };
    expect(await controller.handle({ hello: "hello word" })).toEqual(
      expedtedReturn
    );
  });

  it("should receive a bad string, and receive a bad request", async () => {
    const expedtedError = {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: new Error(`bad Request`),
    };
    expect(await controller.handle({ hello: "aaa" })).toEqual(expedtedError);
  });
});
```

Comment: `handle` is `async`. You need to `await` it.

Comment: @Christian my bad thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to spy your method.

If you are going to add more tests, use `beforeEach` to spy it should be okey, and restore them with `afterEach`, so you could control the returned value.

Your method is async, so your test should also, something like:

```
describe("Hello word Controller ", () => {
  const mockedResponse = { message: "hello word" };

  beforeEach(() => {
    const controllerSpy = jest.spyOn(HelloWordController, "handle");
    controllerSpy.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(mockedResponse));
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  it("should receive a string with name: hello, and value: hello word", async () => {
        const logger = new adptLogger({})
        const hellowordController = new HelloWordController(logger)
        expect(await hellowordController.handle()).toEqual(mockedResponse);
    });
});
```

Comment: but for that reason I'm using beforeEach and afterEach for what?

Comment: I edited it with the code I made, could you look and see if I can improve on something?